# How to use Resource pool for for cleaning the tank in AnyLogic

Tags: simulation, anylogic

When the tank gets empty the valve get close for 30 minutes (this 30 minutes is for cleaning the tank) am using dynamic event for that. as showmen in image below.

[image]

Now what I want to do is

1. use Resoucrepool (a worker) for cleaning the tank.
2. Use Resoucrepool (a worker) for opening and closing the valve.
   Its there any way to achieve that?

Comment: Hi Aqeel, please avoid asking "can X be done" here on SOF. The answer is always "yes". But SOF is not the place to ask "how do I do X". Either use LinkedIn or try it yourself first and ask here on "Why is X not working, I tried Y and Z...". See https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow

Comment: Hay Benjamin, I understand. I read the shared post; it's very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you can do is that on the "on empty" action in the tank, you generate a token, which is an agent called cleaningRequest that goes into a flow that requires a resource (enter-service-sink), and you close all the valves to avoid using that tank.

When the resource is released, or when the token gets to the sink, you open the valves again.

I only answered question 1, but question 2 should follow the same technique